# ES6 Module loading with Webpack and Babel Issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My compiled jsx module scripts are not compiling for some reason.

Here is the directory structure

- dist

  - bundle.js
- node_modules
- scripts

  - helloWorldComponent

    - helloWorldBox.jsx
    - helloWorldDisplay.jsx
  - main.js
- index.html
- package.json
- webpack.config.js

Here are my 2 jsx files

- helloWorldBox.jsx

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import helloWorldDisplay from './helloWorldDisplay.jsx';

var helloWorldBox = React.createClass({
 render : function(){
  return (
   <div>
    <helloWorldDisplay/>
   </div>
  );
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(<helloWorldBox/>, document.getElementById('output'));
```

- helloWorldDisplay.jsx

```html
import React from 'react';

var helloWorldDisplay = React.createClass({
 render : function(){
  return (
   <div>
      Hello World
   </div>
  );
 }
});
```

- main.js file

```html
import helloWorldBox from './helloWorldComponent/helloWorldBox.jsx';
import helloWorldDisplay from './helloWorldComponent/helloWorldDisplay.jsx';
```

When my bundle.js gets created by webpack it looks like this

```html
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

 import helloWorldBox from './helloWorldComponent/helloWorldBox.jsx';
 import helloWorldDisplay from './helloWorldComponent/helloWorldDisplay.jsx';

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

Here is the webpack.config.js file

```html
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
 
module.exports = {
  entry: './scripts/main.js',
  output: { path: __dirname + '/dist', filename: 'bundle.js' },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';

var helloWorldDisplay = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        return (
            <div>
               Hello World
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default helloWorldDisplay
```

Add the export helloworldDisplay file